# How to send recorded audio file to backend flask server?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a frontend application which *records* **Audio** of the meeting.

The **number** of **users** and the **meeting** title and send it to the backend server which is *FLASK(version 1.1.1) run with python 3.7.4.*

I am able to get the Number of *users* and the *meeting title* **but not the audio file**.

### Server code to capture the files.

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET','POST'])
def start_process():
    meeting_name = request.form['topic']
    number_of_user = request.form['numberusr']
    files = request.files['file']
```

I breakpointed it and here is the output.

```
(Pdb) request.form

ImmutableMultiDict([('topic', '3'), ('numberusr ', 'Meeting 2')])
(Pdb) request.files
ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

Flask returning

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2020 18:43:00] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Here is the code how I am sending all the data to the flask server.

### HTML FORM part

```
<form id="upload-file" method="post" action='/upload' enctype="multipart/form-data">

<audio controls id="audio" name="file" class="js-audio form-post-audio" src="">
</audio>
   <fieldset>
        <input name="topic" class="speakernumber">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
     <input name="numberusr " class="meetingname">
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

**When the user presse stop, recording stops and this above form is filled and sent to the flask server. **

### The Ajax code

```
var form_data = new FormData($('#uploadfile')[0]);


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/upload',
    data:form_data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
}).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
});
```

Can someone give full code to send audio(which is recorded) to the backend flask server.